# Formating disappears in the beginning of WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I'm making an RTF Editor in WPF with various formating options (Bold, Italic, Font, Font size etc.) and all that is working as a charm.

But when I start my application and select a different font, the font changes back to the original font as soon as i start to type. If I then delete all the text, select a new font again, the new font is keept and everything is fine from this point on.

I have seen the same behaviour in other editors found on the net, ex. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50139/WPF-RichTextEditor-with-Toolbar

Any hint to overcome this is very much appreciated, since this is about to drive me crazy!

This a simple example that exihibt my problem:

```
<Window x:Class="RTFEditor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=RichTextBox}">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="BtnBold"
                  PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="BtnBold_OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus"
                  Command="ToggleBold"
                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RichTextBox}"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Top">Bold</ToggleButton>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox" SelectionChanged="RichTextBox_OnSelectionChanged"/>
</DockPanel>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace RTFEditor
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RichTextBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var currentValue = RichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);
            BtnBold.IsChecked = (currentValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) && (currentValue != null && currentValue.Equals(FontWeights.Bold));
        }

        private void BtnBold_OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good luck with finding a solution without providing any code that exhibits your problem. That's *not* how we role here... perhaps you should read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page of the Stack Overflow Help Centre?

Comment: @Sheridan How do we role?

Comment: According to the guidelines set out in the Help Center of course.

Comment: @Sheridan Do you mean you mean roll?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Sheridan I'm sorry, but I thought that a link to codeproject solution was enough! And thank you very much for your warm and polite welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this post: [WPF EditingCommands is not working when RichTextBox is just load/empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449205/wpf-editingcommands-is-not-working-when-richtextbox-is-just-load-empty?rq=1) I ended up with a solution consisting of the following methods (my RichTextBox is named Editor!):

```
    private void PrepareEditor(string initalText)
    {
        var run = new Run(initalText);

        if (IsSelectionFormat(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold))
        {
            run.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        }
        if (IsSelectionFormat(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic))
        {
            run.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        }
        if (IsSelectionFormat(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline))
        {
            run.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
        }

        double fontSize;
        if (double.TryParse(CmbFontSize.Text, out fontSize))
            run.FontSize = FontSizeHelper.PxToPt(fontSize);

        if (CmbFontFamily.Text != "")
            run.FontFamily = new FontFamily(CmbFontFamily.Text);

        Editor.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        Editor.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(run));
    }

    private bool IsSelectionFormat(DependencyProperty formattingProperty, object expectedValue)
    {
        object currentValue = Editor.Selection.GetPropertyValue(formattingProperty);
        var active = (currentValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) && (currentValue != null && currentValue.Equals(expectedValue));
        return active;
    }

    private void Editor_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the editor is empty, the Run element is sometimes missing, so we need to add it and apply any selected formating manually!
        if (Editor.PlainText() == "" && Editor.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward).Parent.GetType() != typeof(Run))
        {
            PrepareEditor(e.Text);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Editor_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Editor.PlainText().Trim() == "" && Editor.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward).Parent.GetType() != typeof(Run))
        {
            PrepareEditor("");
        }

        // More code ...
    }
```

Agreed... it looks like a serious hack/workaround, but its the best solution I could find/come up with!